# How to add a header title in people result search?

Tags: 2013, css, people-search

I want to add a header title in people result search?

I want to add here (red square):

[image]

Is there a sharepoint control or anything or is it just not possible?

I want to know too if it is possible to change the color of select arrow (blue square)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Content Editor WebPart and design your Title from Scratch.

[Click here for how to add Content Editor WebPart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-foundation-help/using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA101794745.aspx)

You can also Give a title to Search Results WebPart.
For this just Edit the WebPart Under Title section give a new Title and Choose Title in Chrome type property of WebPart.

For your Second Question:
Their is no OOB way to achieve this. You need to use a custom drop down plugin.

Some plugins are listed below:

http://www.sitepoint.com/16-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

You will be able to make the css changes once you use any of these plugins for the drop down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your steps but 1) under the title, I have "Edit this page to modify your web part content." text that is displayed. 2) How to align with the "select sorting" my content webPart?

Comment: I found for the 1). I has to change Chrome State to "Minimize".

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query